# How to calculate holiday with month and day in python?

Tags: python

I am having difficulties solving the following problem:

"Make a list of national holidays in The Netherlands (assume current year). Write a program that reads a month and day from the user. If the month and day match one of the holidays in the list then your program should display the holiday’s name. Otherwise your program should indicate that the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.

Step-02: Complete solution. The user enters month and day in different lines.
Step-03: Complete solution. The user enters both month and day in one line. Example Input: Month : 5 , Day : 21."

**The code you see below is what I have tried:**

```
    print("Calculate holiday from month and day\n")
    number_of_month = int(input("Please enter the month:"))
    number_of_day = int(input("Please enter the day:"))
    
    def holiday():
        return{
            1: {
                1: "New Year"
            },
            4: {
                15: "Good Friday"
            },
            4: {    
                17: "Easter Sunday"
            },
            4: { 
                18: "Easter Monday"
            },
            4: { 
                27: "Kingsday"
            },
            5: {    
                5: "Liberation Day"
            },
            5: {    
                26: "Ascension Day"
            },
            5: {    
                6: "White Sunday"
            },
            6: {    
                6: "White Monday"
            },
            25: {   
                12: "Christmas Day"
            },
            26: {   
                12: "2nd Christmas Day"
            }
        }
    
if number_of_month and number_of_day == holiday:
    print(holiday)
else:
    print("the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.")
```

Sorry in advance if I am asking a dumb question.

Comment: The outer dict has months as keys; your last for entries have the days and months swapped.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even see it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major issue with using the day as the outer key. Days are not unique, and it would be impossible to support a case of 2 or more holidays that happen to be on the same day but in a different month. A more robust approach would be to use the month as the outer keys and the days as the inner keys.

After changing that, notice that `holiday` returns the dictionary, so you need to check if the provided day and month exist. The below example takes advantage of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) in order to not raise a `KeyError`.

```py
holiday_name = holiday().get(number_of_month, {}).get(number_of_day)
if holiday_name is not None:
    print(holiday_name)
else:
    print("the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.")
```

Or without [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```py
try:
    holiday_name = holiday()[number_of_month][number_of_day]
except KeyError:
    print("the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.")
else:
    print(holiday_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! if dict is not handy in this situation, could i use a list to solve this problem?

Comment: I did not say the dict was not handy, just that it wasn't used correctly, and I also suggested how it should be used.

Comment: Okay i will try to fix it with both of your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not the best, but you can try to switch key for event holiday and date as value since the event itself is unique. Then you could iterate over it and yield the key if its value match user input. Using yield will generator but it can solve when 2 or more holiday events occur in the same date. Using list you can check if the list itself is empty or not. If it not empty, print its element which is the key of holiday's dict.

```
print("Calculate holiday from month and day")
number_of_month = int(input("Please enter the month : "))
number_of_day = int(input("Please enter the day : "))

def get_holiday(month, day):

    # event as key and date as value of holiday dict
    holiday = {
            "New Year": (1, 1),
            "Good Friday": (4, 15),
            "Easter Sunday": (4, 17),
            "Easter Monday": (4, 18),
            "Kingsday": (4, 27),
            "Liberation Day": (5, 5),
            "Other Holiday": (5, 5),   # added holiday in the same date
            "Ascension Day": (5, 26),
            "White Sunday": (5, 6),
            "White Monday": (6, 6),
            "Christmas Day": (12, 25),
            "2nd Christmas Day": (12, 26)
        }
    # iterate holiday dict if user input is equals dict value
    for event, date in holiday.items():
        if (month, day) == date: yield event # if equal, yield key (returning generator)

# Turn get_holiday function to list
holidays = list(get_holiday(number_of_month, number_of_day))

# check if list of holiday is empty or not
if len(holidays):
    for holiday in holidays: print(holiday)
else:
    print("the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.")
```

Output:

```
Calculate holiday from month and day
Please enter the month : 5
Please enter the day : 5
Liberation Day
Other Holiday

Calculate holiday from month and day
Please enter the month : 1
Please enter the day : 2
the entered month and day do not correspond to a fixed-date holiday.

Calculate holiday from month and day
Please enter the month : 12
Please enter the day : 25
Christmas Day
```

Comment: This is the code I was trying to write before I got confused by my self and I eventually went with a different approach. Thank you for explaining it with the comments

Comment: No problem. Pay attention to duplicated key.